# Como fazer "position: fixed;" no topo e que fique por cima de tudo?

Tags: css, posicionamento

Estou precisando por uma div fixa no topo da tela (até aí, basta usar o `position: fixed`), mas que não seja sobreposta por outras divs e imagens. Ela tem que ficar por cima de tudo.

"Organização":

```
<html>
<head>
[brain]
</head>
<body>
<div class="a div que precisa estar no topo, fixa e por cima de tudo"></div>
[resto do site, que quando há scroll, sobrepõe a div acima]
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```css
 .beta-info {
    background: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #FF016D;
    position: fixed;
   }
```

```html
<div id="site">
  
<div class="beta-info">O SITE ESTÁ EM FASE BETA, BUGS SÃO COMUNS!</div>
[resto do site, sobrepõe a div acima]

</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Coloca um z-index nela, maior que qualquer elemento seu que possua z-index.

Comment: É isso mesmo, mas seria legal incluir um exemplo. E recomendo usar um valor alto para o `z-index`, pois outros elementos sem z-index explícito possuem um `z-index` implícito.

Comment: Eu ia postar um exemplo mas além de ser algo bem simples é muito desagradável codar no celular dentro do trem rs.

Comment: Inclui o exemplo depois então, porque tenho certeza que vai ter gente querendo mandar deletar sua resposta por ser curta/simples demais. E boa viagem! :)

Comment: ôxente, Danylo, você tá no trem, se cadastrou no [pt.so], respondeu e já ganhou 15 pontos, ¡olé!

Comment: Eu consegui, agradeço. O resultado está nesse link: http://centerload.particao.com/